# Give user points when he sign in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, controller

In my app if **user1** likes a picture from **user2** he clicks on "get it now" button,and the points from **user1** goes to **user2**.And user1 respectively gets redirected to the final picture.
This is what i use in my controller

```
  def downloadpage
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      if current_user.points >= @picure.pointsneeded 
        current_user.points -= @picture.pointsneeded
        @picture.user.points += @picture.pointsneeded
        current_user.save
        @picture.user.save
        redirect_to @picture.boxlink
      else
        redirect_to :back, notice: "You don't have enough points"
      end
    end
  end
```

> **Question:** how to give my user 7000 points when they sign up into my website,for the first time?

i tried to put in my application controller

```
before_filter :give_points_to_last_user

  def give_points_to_last_user
    @user = User.last
    @user.points = 7000
    @user.save
  end
```

And it did work,but the above system didn't work,how many time the user hits the "get this picture button",the 7000 points remain the same,they don't decrease as expected,it just stays 7000,whatever i do.

My User Controller right now

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
  end 

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
  end

  private

  # Use strong_parameters for attribute whitelisting
  # Be sure to update your create() and update() controller methods.

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, :points)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Users Controller -

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  @user.update(points: 7000)
end
```

Try Above code.

Comment: I added my user controller,in my question,where would you advice me to add this? into the create method?

Comment: Yes in create method, when user creates.

Comment: This is very weird,it seems like my rails app creates the user not from the user controller,because (as experiment),i temporary deleted everything there and the user registration was working fine.Would you mind to give me your bitbucket username,i will send an invitation,if you can take a look,where i should add the line you mentioned above.

Comment: Not received yet, Can we talk through skype, where my username is "amitkumarsuroliya".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77548/discussion-between-amit-suroliya-and-mike-mccallen).